# Quasi-coherent sheaves on classifying stacks

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, algebraic-groups, stacks, classifying-spaces

Let $G$ be a smooth group scheme over some base $S$. Then we have the $S$-stack $BG$ whose $T$-points are the $G$-torsors on $T$. Under which conditions do we have $\mathsf{Qcoh}(BG) \simeq \mathrm{Rep}_S(G)$?
I think it holds when $G$ is affine and étale over $S$. I am interested in more general assumptions and references to the literature (because I don't know any). I am sure that this is well-known, but I'm not sure where to look.

Comment: You should have a look at Laumon and Moret-Bailly, 13.3.6 and 13.3.7.

Comment: Ok they give this as an exercise / without explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would help to specify what topology you are choosing on schemes over $S$ when you define the stack $BG$.  Since you specify that $G \to S$ is a smooth surjection, let's assume smooth surjections are covers in our topology.  Smooth surjections are stable effective descent morphisms for quasicoherent sheaves, so pullback along the cover $S \to BG$ induces an equivalence of categories between quasicoherent sheaves on $BG$ and $G$-equivariant quasicoherent sheaves on $S$ (equivalently, representations of $G$).  That is, there are no additional conditions necessary beyond your initial assumption.

More generally, you can take $G \times_S G \to G \leftrightarrows S$ any fpqc group object, as long as $BG$ is viewed as a stack in the fpqc topology.

Comment: Thanks! Can you give a reference where all this is proven *in detail*? (It's not that I don't understand it, but rather I need a good reference in my thesis.)

Comment: The equivalence in question is mostly a special case of http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/06WT where $U=S$ and $R=G$.  I do not have a good single reference for the fact that you can weaken fppf to fpqc by taking a suitable stackification of $BG$, but it follows from descent properties of quasi-coherent sheaves (http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/023T ).

Comment: Ok that's the first part, but how to come from G-equiv sheaves to G-reps? Basically I know how this works, but again I don't know a reference to the literature.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0412512 Proposition 3.48, setting $X=S$ and $\mathcal{F}$ to be the fibered category of quasicoherent sheaves.

Comment: Thank you. Honestly, I'm very confused. But I accept your answer because probably others will benefit from the references.